# R-evalue with multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidy

I have a series of variables (from a survey) with the values (1,2,5,6). I want to change the values of a specific set of variables from 5 to 3 and the 6 to 4. In this example I've only included the variables Q11_1:Q11_13 that I am interested in changing. There about 100 other variables I have not included in the example.

```
survey<- read_table2("Q11_1 Q11_2   Q11_3   Q11_4   Q11_5   Q11_6   Q11_7   Q11_8   Q11_9   Q11_10  Q11_11  Q11_12  Q11_13
2   5   5   2   5   5   5   5   2   5   5   2   2
1   1   1   2   2   5   5   5   1   2   2   2   1
6   5   6   6   6   6   5   6   5   6   6   6   6
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5   5   6   6   5
")
```

I know I can use revalue to change the values like this:

```
survey$Q11_1 <- revalue(survey$Q11_1, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_2 <- revalue(survey$Q11_2, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_3 <- revalue(survey$Q11_3, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_4 <- revalue(survey$Q11_4, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_5 <- revalue(survey$Q11_5, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_6 <- revalue(survey$Q11_6, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_7 <- revalue(survey$Q11_7, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_8 <- revalue(survey$Q11_8, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_9 <- revalue(survey$Q11_9, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_10 <- revalue(survey$Q11_10, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_11 <- revalue(survey$Q11_11, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_12 <- revalue(survey$Q11_12, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
survey$Q11_13 <- revalue(survey$Q11_13, c('5'='3','6'='4'))
```

Is there a way to apply this revaluing (or some other function) in a more efficient way? My solution seems unnecessarily chunky. Any help appreciated. I was hoping for a pipe/dplyr solution.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution matching the column name "Q11"

```r
library(tidyverse)

survey<- read_table2("Q11_1 Q11_2   Q11_3   Q11_4   Q11_5   Q11_6   Q11_7   Q11_8   Q11_9   Q11_10  Q11_11  Q11_12  Q11_13
2   5   5   2   5   5   5   5   2   5   5   2   2
1   1   1   2   2   5   5   5   1   2   2   2   1
6   5   6   6   6   6   5   6   5   6   6   6   6
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5
6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5   5   6   6   5
")


survey %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("Q11"),.fns = ~ case_when(.x == 5 ~ 3,
                                                   .x == 6 ~ 4,
                                                   TRUE ~ .x)))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 13
#>   Q11_1 Q11_2 Q11_3 Q11_4 Q11_5 Q11_6 Q11_7 Q11_8 Q11_9 Q11_10 Q11_11 Q11_12
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     2     3     3     2     3     3     3     3     2      3      3      2
#> 2     1     1     1     2     2     3     3     3     1      2      2      2
#> 3     4     3     4     4     4     4     3     4     3      4      4      4
#> 4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4      4      4      4
#> 5     3     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4      4      4      4
#> 6     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     3      3      4      4
#> # ... with 1 more variable: Q11_13 <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: when I run this code, it does not show me the same results that you see. Those 6's and 5's remain... any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: Do you have dplyr 1.0.0?

Comment: Hey is there a way to limit this to only certain groups, for instance, I want to revalue those columns only if condition==1. I've tried tweaking your code with no luck.

Comment: no problem, you just need to change the condition using where, do you want to post it as another question and tag me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524529/re-value-selection-of-columns-by-group Thanks!